# Incrementing characters in a particular pattern in C#

Tags: c#, .net

The program should take in a parameter N and print out N + 1 lines.
I have to output something like this.

This is the output which I must get at N = 5

> A       //Increment by 0
>
> AB      //Increment by 1
>
> ACE     //Increment by 2
>
> ADGJ    //Increment by 3
>
> AEIMQ   //Increment by 4

The algorithm uses N as the number of characters to skip in between each add. So at N=3, it's A skip 3 to D, skip 3 to G, skip three to J.

And when the program runs out of upper case characters(i.e. When N is too big), it should start with lower case characters and if it runs out of lower case then it should again start with upper case and so on.
I am a novice to programming. And I dont really know where to start. I've been working around the loops for a while and still have no clue what-so-ever.

Comment: the algorithm you want to use is not so clear, and what did you try before ?

Comment: I have tried to create a char array comprising of alphabets from A-Z and then tried to use for and foreach loops. But I dont have much idea about what I am doing right now

Comment: create an array on 52 length, save upper/lowercase alphabets in it, do  a while loop and select from array incrementing according to value N, and print the letters, and before picking up from the array do a modulus on your index with 52 e.g arr[i%52].

Comment: Can you explain that algorithm?  For instance, why `ACE` when `N=3`?

Comment: Like on line 1 it should print out A, then on line 2 it should print out AB(incrementing by 1), on line 3 it should increment by 2 and print out ACE and so on

Comment: Yes this is my homework but I've tried a few things already and have almost reached a dead-end.

Comment: char[] arrString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
Something like this

Comment: This is all what is mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach using a `Char[]`, `modulo`, `StringBuilder` and a `for-loop` which increments by `n` for efficiency:

```
readonly static Char[] letters = 
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();

static String appendChars(int n)
{
    int length = n + 1;
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder("A", length);

    for (int i = n; sBuilder.Length < length; i += n)
    {
        Char nextChar = letters[i % letters.Length];
        sBuilder.Append(nextChar);
    }

    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

test your sample data:

```
int n = 5;
IEnumerable<String> allWords = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => appendChars(i));
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allWords));
```

outputs:

```
A
AB 
ACE 
ADGJ 
AEIMQ
```

Here's the demo: http://ideone.com/0sspY

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
public string GetOutPut(int increment)
{
    string alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    string output = string.Empty;

    for(int i=0; i<=increment; i++)
    {
       int index = i*increment;

       if(index>alphabets.Length)
          index = index % alphabets.Length;

       output+= alphabets[index];
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll try to use your method.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you get the number of lines that you want - because you said `N+1` but your example gives only `N` lines.

The following can be used to generate each one of those individual lines, and the `Algo` method can be modified to generate `n+1` lines by sticking the code in a while loop, decrementing `n` and `len` and using `AppendLine` on the `StringBuilder`:

```
char[] allowedChars = Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Concat(Enumerable.Range('a', 26))
  .Select(i => (char)i).ToArray();

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
  Assert.AreEqual("A", Algo(0, 1));
  Assert.AreEqual("AB", Algo(1, 2));
  Assert.AreEqual("ACE", Algo(2, 3));
  Assert.AreEqual("ADGJ", Algo(3, 4));
  Assert.AreEqual("AEIMQ", Algo(4, 5));
}

public string Algo(int n, int len)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  int nextCharIndex = 0;
  for (int f = 0; f < len; f++)
  {
    sb.Append(allowedChars[nextCharIndex]);
    //the `%`, or mod, here wraps around the next character back to upper case
    nextCharIndex = (nextCharIndex + n) % allowedChars.Length;
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It almost instantly gave the output that I required.